# I want to specific data which concerned to input value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon. From the topic, I want a query to show data from input to see where it's concerned to With 2 columns. For example,  below table is the list of old and new machine ID. I want to see what IDs of PBGM7D related from before it's become PBGM7D.

```
Old_MC_ID | New_MC_ID |
__________|___________|
PBG7A     | PBBM7A
TESTMC1   | TESTMC11
PPO230    | PPPO230
PBBM7A    | PBG7A
TESTMC11  | TESTMC11A
TESTMC11A | TESTMC1A
PBG7A     | PBGM7A
OV11      | OV1
PBGM7A    | PBGM7D
```

And the query result I want something like this.

```
History_ID  |
____________|
PBGM7D
PBGM7A
PBG7A
PBBM7A
PBG7A
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't, I suggest looking up an rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression).

Comment: @Larnu  Now, I tried to identify each MC/No. by insert new column and set identity specification to them but thank you so much for your suggestion about rCTE. I think I have more choices to looking for now.

Comment: @puydan  . . . Can an id return to an already used id?  That is, are there cycles?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you mean return new id as old id when edit or add. So yes, they're.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive CTE as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  OldId VARCHAR(10),
  NewId VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('ID1', 'ID2'),
('ID10', 'ID11'),
('ID2', 'ID3'),
('ID3', 'ID4'),
('ID7', 'ID8');

WITH C AS
(
  SELECT OldId,
         NewId
  FROM T
  WHERE OldId = 'ID1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.OldId,
         T.NewId
  FROM T JOIN C
  ON T.OldId = C.NewId
)
SELECT OldId History
FROM C
UNION
SELECT NewId
FROM C;
--OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+
| History |
+---------+
| ID1     |
| ID2     |
| ID3     |
| ID4     |
+---------+
```

**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb46ed53cd435f40f12828c872592bac)**

Comment: Many thanks for your code. But the problem I've got is about maximum recursion(I forgot to tell you that there're possible ways about duplicate data in the table) Do you have some solution to protect maximum recursion without any error massage?

Comment: @puydan Just add `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)`